# Invert jQuery Sparkline Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery Sparkline graphs by Omnipotent and want to know if there is any way to invert the graph?

```
$(".sparkline").sparkline("html", {
    height: "1.5em",
    width: "8em",
    lineColor: '#23c6c8',
    fillColor: '#23c6c85e',
    minSpotColor: !1,
    maxSpotColor: !1,
    spotColor: '#f0f0f0',
    spotRadius: 3,
    tooltipFormat: '@{{offset:offset}} @{{value}}',
    tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': {!! json_encode($dateArray) !!}
    },
});
```

Currently the higher the number supplied the higher the graph point, I want it to be the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by reversing the chart and unreversing the tooltip using the formatter.

Multiplied everything by -1 and added to the sparkline chart
Added this:

```
tooltipFormatter: function(sparkline, options, point) {
            return Math.abs(point.y)+'º '+Math.abs(options.userOptions.tooltipValueLookups.points.map[point.y]) + ' pts.';
        },
```

To the options, which returns Xº Z pts. (in my case that just did it).

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error when I implement it

Comment: You can also try these links:
http://biostall.com/inverting-the-y-axis-on-jquery-flot-graph/
https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/issues/40
https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about (recommended)

Comment: Thanks for the above but they did not help, one was for Flot Graphs which are different. The other 2 are not working solutions.